# Issue while accessing data from Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

When accessing data using [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/%7Bid%7D), it is failing with 400 bad request without any error details. **{id}** is the value received from the response of https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups.

Following response is returned.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthenticationError",
        "message": "Error authenticating with resource",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-10-15T15:01:43",
            "request-id": "1d82fe40-5186-46fc-9fb7-c16341eb1ffb",
            "client-request-id": "29c9e68d-bfd8-6f53-65c4-c49a82581a76"
        }
    }
}
```

We tried using MS graph SDK as well as graph explorer. All the consent are given for the end point.

What could be the reason for the error?

Comment: If I call /beta/groups and use the first group ID to call /beta/teams/{ID} it just works (only consented Group.Read.All and Team.ReadBasic.All). Are you sure your request body is empty and the access_token contains the correct scopes?

Comment: It is, the issue is happening for some specific tenants not all.

Comment: Does without error details mean no request id or timestamp? If those are available in the error response please share. If not the the request may be failing from client side. Could you share may be raw logs of the error without PII?

Comment: @Danstan I have added the response.